# Receive 404 Not Found for a Flask app when I use Nginx as reverse proxy with Gunicorn socket

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, flask

I have been following the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) to deploy my own flask app to my Ubuntu 16 server. I used `Nginx` as a reverse proxy to pass requests to a `gunicorn` socket. Just in case anyone wants to know `ufw` is allowed for `Nginx All`.

**Here is what I tried so far:**

1. I checked if the `Flask` app ran on the local server by running the application locally on port `5000` (worked fine)
2. I checked if gunicorn was able to serve by running : `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app` (worked fine)
3. I made the `/etc/systemd/system/myapp_service.service` file (below)

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve my app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/app/flaskapp
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app_env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix
:/var/www/app/flaskapp/myapp.sock -m 002 wsgi:app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. I made an `Nginx` configuration file in `sites-available` as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/app/flaskapp/myapp.sock;
    }
}
```

5. I made a symbolic link to `sites-enabled`, ran  `sudo nginx -t`
6. Restarted `Nginx` and `myapp_service` with `systemctl`
7. When I go to `http://app.mydomain.com` it just shows me that big "Welcome to Nginx" page instead of my app.

What more do I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

probably this one is wrong:

> proxy_pass **http**://**unix**:/var/www/app/flaskapp/myapp.sock;

Try to leave only this part:

`proxy_pass unix:/var/www/app/flaskapp/myapp.sock;`

Comment: No the way I wrote is what is correct, according to `nginx`. If I remove http:// the `sudo nginx -t` syntax check fails